# Animation of falling object not working on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sass

I have a animtaion for falling objects inside a div. I tested it in all browsers and its works properly but on IE it doesn't animate at all. I ask for your help, thank you!

It works for both Desktop Size and in Mobile devices, it works on Google Chrome, Mozilla, Edge, Safarri, Opera except on IE

here is my SCSS code:

```
   .falling__Object span {
        display: inline-block;
        z-index: 10000;
        -webkit-animation: falling__Object 10s infinite linear;
        -moz-animation: falling__Object 10s infinite linear;

        &.leaves {
            width: 5vw;
            background: url(../img/section-countdown/leaf.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 75%;
            /* margin: -280px 84px 54px -34px; 

            @media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width:500px) {
                width: 5vwvw;
            }*/
        }

        &.snow {
            width: 5vw;
            margin: -280px 84px 54px -34px;
            background: url("../img/section-countdown/snow.gif");
            background-size: 70%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        &.green-leaf {
            width: 5vw;
            margin: -280px 84px 54px -34px;
            background: url("../img/section-countdown/green-leaf.png");
            background-size: 70%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        &.spring {
            width: 5vw;
            margin: -280px 84px 54px -34px;
            background: url("../img/section-countdown/spring-leaf.png");
            background-size: 70%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
    }

    .falling__Object span:nth-child(1n+5) {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 1.3s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 1.3s;
    }

    .falling__Object span:nth-child(3n+2) {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 1.5s;
    }

    .falling__Object span:nth-child(2n+5) {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 1.7s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 1.7s;
    }

    .falling__Object span:nth-child(3n+10) {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 2.7s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 2.7s;
    }

    .falling__Object span:nth-child(7n+2) {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 3.5s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 3.5s;
    }

    .falling__Object span:nth-child(4n+5) {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 5.5s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 5.5s;
    }

    .falling__Object span:nth-child(3n+7) {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 8s;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes falling__Object {
        0% {
            opacity: 1;
            -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0px) rotateZ(0deg);
        }

        75% {
            opacity: 1;
            -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 600px) rotateZ(270deg);
        }

        100% {
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transform: translate(150px, 800px) rotateZ(360deg);
        }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes falling__Object {
        0% {
            opacity: 1;
            -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0px) rotateZ(0deg);
        }

        75% {
            opacity: 1;
            -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 600px) rotateZ(270deg);
        }

        100% {
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transform: translate(150px, 800px) rotateZ(360deg);
        }
    }
```

and here is the script:

```
function getSeason() {
    var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
    if (currentMonth === 12 || currentMonth === 1 || currentMonth === 2) {
        $(".falling__Object span").addClass("snow");
    } else if (currentMonth >= 3 && currentMonth <= 5) {
        $(".falling__Object span").addClass("spring");
    } else if (currentMonth >= 6 && currentMonth <= 8) {
        $(".falling__Object span").addClass("green-leaf");
    } else if (currentMonth >= 9 && currentMonth <= 11) {
        $(".falling__Object span").addClass("leaves");
    }
    return ""
}
```

Comment: the web developers old question, what version of ie?

Comment: Internet Explorer 11

Comment: What are your expecting if you're only adding `-webkit` and `-moz` vendor prefixed properties?

Comment: @connexo im am sorry that I forgot the animation:; , please dont be mad or something, im not a robot, im just a beginner in web development

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the css properties compatible with ie11 (the un-prefixed) for animation, transform & keyframes

```
.falling__Object span {
        display: inline-block;
        z-index: 10000;
        -webkit-animation: falling__Object 10s infinite linear;
        -moz-animation: falling__Object 10s infinite linear;
        animation: falling__Object 10s infinite linear;

        &.leaves {
            width: 5vw;
            background: url(../img/section-countdown/leaf.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 75%;
            /* margin: -280px 84px 54px -34px; 

            @media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width:500px) {
                width: 5vwvw;
            }*/
        }

        &.snow {
            width: 5vw;
            margin: -280px 84px 54px -34px;
            background: url("../img/section-countdown/snow.gif");
            background-size: 70%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        &.green-leaf {
            width: 5vw;
            margin: -280px 84px 54px -34px;
            background: url("../img/section-countdown/green-leaf.png");
            background-size: 70%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }

        &.spring {
            width: 5vw;
            margin: -280px 84px 54px -34px;
            background: url("../img/section-countdown/spring-leaf.png");
            background-size: 70%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
    }

    .falling__Object span:nth-child(1n+5) {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 1.3s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 1.3s;
        animation-delay: 1.3s;
    }

    .falling__Object span:nth-child(3n+2) {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 1.5s;
        animation-delay: 1.5s;
    }

    .falling__Object span:nth-child(2n+5) {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 1.7s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 1.7s;
        animation-delay: 1.7s;
    }

    .falling__Object span:nth-child(3n+10) {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 2.7s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 2.7s;
        animation-delay: 2.7s;
    }

    .falling__Object span:nth-child(7n+2) {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 3.5s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 3.5s;
        animation-delay: 3.5s;
    }

    .falling__Object span:nth-child(4n+5) {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 5.5s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 5.5s;
        animation-delay: 5.5s;
    }

    .falling__Object span:nth-child(3n+7) {
        -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 8s;
        animation-delay: 8s;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes falling__Object {
        0% {
            opacity: 1;
            -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0px) rotateZ(0deg);
            transform: translate(0, 0px) rotateZ(0deg);
        }

        75% {
            opacity: 1;
            -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 600px) rotateZ(270deg);
            transform: translate(100px, 600px) rotateZ(270deg);
        }

        100% {
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transform: translate(150px, 800px) rotateZ(360deg);
            transform: translate(150px, 800px) rotateZ(360deg);
        }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes falling__Object {
        0% {
            opacity: 1;
            -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0px) rotateZ(0deg);
            transform: translate(0, 0px) rotateZ(0deg);
        }

        75% {
            opacity: 1;
            -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 600px) rotateZ(270deg);
            transform: translate(100px, 600px) rotateZ(270deg);
        }

        100% {
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transform: translate(150px, 800px) rotateZ(360deg);
            transform: translate(150px, 800px) rotateZ(360deg);
        }
    }
    @keyframes falling__Object {
        0% {
            opacity: 1;
            -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0px) rotateZ(0deg);
            transform: translate(0, 0px) rotateZ(0deg);
        }

        75% {
            opacity: 1;
            -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 600px) rotateZ(270deg);
            transform: translate(100px, 600px) rotateZ(270deg);
        }

        100% {
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transform: translate(150px, 800px) rotateZ(360deg);
            transform: translate(150px, 800px) rotateZ(360deg);
        }
    }
```

Comment: oh sorry, it still not animating in IE but its working on other browsers

Comment: Works fine now on IE for me! Thank you so much for helping me out!  ありがとうございました!